# Regex - how to split string by commas, omitting commas in brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, say:

`$str = "myTemplate, testArr => [1868,1869,1870], testInteger => 3, testString => 'test, can contain a comma'"`

It basically represents a comma delimited list of parameters I need to parse.

I need to split this string in PHP (probably using `preg_match_all`) by commas (but omitting those in brackets and quotes) so the end result would be array of the following four matches:

```
myTemplate
testArr => [1868,1869,1870]
testInteger => 3
testString => 'test, can contain a comma'
```

The problem is with the array and string values. So any commas inside [ ] or ' ' or " " should not be considered as a delimiter.

There are many similar questions here, but I wasn't able to get it working for this particular situation. What would be the correct regex to get this result? Thank you!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Can you share EXACTLY, not roughly what your data looks like

Comment: @PavneetSingh You have changed an already vague description into something else. **care required when editing questions**

Comment: @RiggsFolly The string can look exactly like as I wrote it.

I have tried: `\[(?:[^()]|(?R))+\]|'[^']*'|[^()\[\],]+` which separates the brackets as a signle match, which is not the intended result.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it a bit less confusing. However the task should be quite clear.

Comment: tomage i meant to add your regex pattern to your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
$str = "myTemplate, testArr => [1868,1869,1870], testInteger => 3, testString => 'test, can contain a comma'";

$arr = preg_split("/\s*,\s*(?![^][]*\])(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)/", $str);

print_r( $arr );
```

There are 2 lookarounds used in this regex:

- `(?![^][]*\])` - Asserts comma is not inside `[...]`
- `(?=(?:(?:[^']*'){2})*[^']*$)` - Asserts comma is not inside `'...'`

**PS:** This is assuming we don't have unbalanced/nested/escaped quotes and brackets.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aXomba/1)

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => myTemplate
    [1] => testArr => [1868,1869,1870]
    [2] => testInteger => 3
    [3] => testString => 'test, can contain a comma'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I wound do it like this:

```
<?php

$str = "myTemplate, testArr => [1868,1869,1870], testInteger => 3, testString => 'test, can contain a comma'";


$pattern[0] = "[a-zA-Z]+,"; // textonly entry
$pattern[1] = "\w+\s*?=>\s*\[.*\]\s*,?"; // array type entry with value enclosed in square brackets
$pattern[2] = "\w+\s*?=>\s*\d+\s*,?"; // array type entry with decimal value
$pattern[3] = "\w+\s*?=>\s*\'.*\'\s*,?"; // array type entry with string value

$regex = implode('|', $pattern);

preg_match_all("/$regex/", $str, $matches);

// You can also use the one liner commented below if you dont like to use the array
//preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z]+,|\w+\s*?=>\s*\[.*\]\s*,?|\w+\s*?=>\s*\d+\s*,?|\w+\s*?=>\s*\'.*\'\s*,?/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

This is easier to manage and I can easily add/remove patterns if needed. It will output like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => myTemplate,
        [1] => testArr => [1868,1869,1870],
        [2] => testInteger => 3,
        [3] => testString => 'test, can contain a comma'
    )

)
```